# Paint.setAlpha() sums up, if called several times

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, alpha, live-wallpaper

I am writing a LiveWallpaper for Android and I want to have a Bitmap with a certain amount of opacity to show.

In the constructor of my LiveWallpaper Engine I set a Paint that I will use later on my Canvas:

```
MyEngine() {
    ...
    mForeGroundPaint = new Paint();
    mForeGroundPaint.setAlpha(5);
}
```

I draw the Bitmap in this function, using the `mForeGroundPaint` on the `drawBitmap()`:

```
void drawFrame() {
    final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
    Canvas c = null;
    try {
        c = holder.lockCanvas();
        if (c != null) {
            c.save();
            /* allows the wallpaper to scroll through the homescreens */
            c.drawBitmap(wpBitmap, screenWidth * -mOffset, 0,
                    mForeGroundPaint);
            c.restore();
        }
    } finally {
        if (c != null)
                 holder.unlockCanvasAndPost©;
    }
}
```

What happens now is, that everything seems to work fine, what means that the Bitmap is painted with the opacity value of `5`, like I set it.

The *problem* happens when I use that `drawFrame()` function several times, as it is called during `onOffsetsChanged()`: *The opacity sums up, making it 10, 15, 20, 25, ... with every call of `drawFrame()`.*

How can I prevent that from happening, and thus keep the amount of opacity on a steady level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Bitmap` is just being redrawn over old ones, so you have 2 `Bitmap`s at 5% opacity = 10% opacity. Try clearing the `Canvas` with `c.drawColor(...);` (with your background color) after `c.save();`.